# Angular Material - sticky "header" w/ md-select options breaks layout when md-backdrop applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a filter bar for a table above the table set to become sticky at a certain height, this works great until you open the `md-select options` and it triggers the `md-backdrop` and applies inline positioning to the body and moves everything but the fixed positioned filter bar.

Is there anyway to disable the inline positioning that gets applied to `<body>` when the select options dropdown opens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent body from ever getting set to anything other than what you want it to be with display:block !important or display:flex !important. Whatever you want really, it will override the inline css that angular material's javascript applies.